# Reading in stops after handling exception inside loop

Tags: java, oop, indexoutofboundsexception

I'd have a pretty strange question here. After throwing and handling my ReaderException exception my read-in still stops at the first occurence of the exception. Can somebody please explain why is this happening?

Input:

```
Hotel Paradis;Strada Ciocarliei, Cluj-Napoca 400124;46.779862;23.611739;7;200;8;250;1;400
Hotel Sunny Hill;Strada Fagetului 31A, Cluj-Napoca 400497;46.716030;23.573740;4;150;6;190
Golden Tulip Ana Dome;Strada Observatorului 129, Cluj-Napoca 400352;46.751989;23.576580;0;330;0;350;0;600
```

Code:

```
public HotelDescriptor readLine(final String line) throws ReaderException {
    System.out.println(line);
    String info[] = line.split(";");
    for (String i:info)
        System.out.println(i);
    String tempname = info[0];
    String tempaddress = info[1];
    float templatitudeh = Float.parseFloat(info[2]);
    float templongitudeh = Float.parseFloat(info[3]);
    int singleroom = Integer.parseInt(info[4]);
    int singleprice = Integer.parseInt(info[5]);
    int doubleroom = Integer.parseInt(info[6]);
    int doubleprice = Integer.parseInt(info[7]);
    int suiteroom = Integer.parseInt(info[8]);
    int suiteprice = Integer.parseInt(info[9]);

    Hotel tempHotel = new Hotel(tempname, tempaddress, templatitudeh, templongitudeh, singleroom, singleprice, doubleroom, doubleprice, suiteroom, suiteprice);
    System.out.println(tempHotel.getName());
    return tempHotel;
    }
public List<HotelDescriptor> readFile(final String hotels) {
    try (BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(hotels))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = buff.readLine() )!= null) {try {
                hotelData.add(readLine(line));
            } catch (ReaderException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            //line = buff.readLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hotelData;
}
```

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz that one is separated by a ",", therefore is NOT split, remains a string : Strada Ciocarliei, Cluj-Napoca 400124 .

Comment: before you parse the line, you should check that the length of the array returned by split is at least of the proper length (10) and then before you parse the indices you should check that string matches that format with a simple regex

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz once again, please watch out. My field delimiter is the ";" not the "," . Given the input, it creates an array of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that **hotelData** is declared as a Class field (class global).

When reading in a text file you should take into consideration some anomalies that can happen (or not). Simple steps can be taken to ensure that reading of that text file will be relatively successful. If your application is creating the text file then your success rate raises considerably since you can control how it is written but, if your application is not creating the text file or the text file is compiled from remote sources then the success rate can be reduced unless steps are taken to ensure expected results.

**In my opinion:**

- A text file should be identifiable so as to ensure that the proper
  text file is actually being read to process. If the text data is from
  a CSV file then a **CSV Header** line should be the very first line
  within the file and a read of this line should be done and compared
  to so as to verify that the correct file is being accessed. This is
  especially true if the file is to be selectable by any number of
  Users (perhaps by way of a file chooser). If a **File Identifier**
  (or Descriptor) line does not exist within your text file as the **first line** of
  the file then perhaps you should consider using one even if it is
  considered a **Comment Line** where the line might start with perhaps
  a semi-colon (**;**) as the first character of the line. Anything
  that can identify the file as being the correct file to process.
- Blank lines and any lines deemed to be **Comment Lines** should be
  ignored. This includes any file lines known **not** to be actual **Data
  Lines** whatever they may be. In general, a couple lines of code
  consisting of an **if** statement along with a few conditions can
  take care of this situation.
- Never count on actual **Data Lines** (the lines of data you will be
  processing) to be holding all the required data expected. This is
  especially true when manipulating **split** delimited data with
  methods such as **Integer.parseInt()** or **Float.parseFloat()** as a
  mere examples. This is actually the biggest problem in your particular
  situation. Take note of the example data lines you have provided
  within your post. The first line consists of 10 delimited pieces of
  data, the second data line consists of **8** delimited pieces of
  data, and the third line consists of again, 10 pieces of delimited
  data. It is the **second data line** that is the issue here. When
  this line is split the result will be an Array (**info[]**) which
  will hold 8 elements (index 0 to 7) yet the **readLine()** method is
  expecting to **always** deal with an array consisting of 10 elements
  (index 0 to 9). While processing the second data line, guess what
  happens when the code line `int suiteroom = Integer.parseInt(info[8]);` is         hit. That's right, you get a
  **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** because there simply is no index **8** within the **info[]** array. You need to handle situations like this in your code and prepare to deal with them. Don't rely on
  exception handling to take care of business for you. The whole idea
  is to **avoid exceptions** if at all possible mind you there are times when it is necessary. I don't believe this is one of them.

Without access to your code classes I'm just going to naturally assume that your method returns are valid and functioning as planned. With this in mind, here is how I would format the Hotels text file:

```
My App Name - Hotels Data File

;Hotel Name; Hotel Address; Latitude; Longtitude; Single Room; Single Price; Double Room; Double Price; Suite Room; Suite Price

Hotel Paradis;Strada Ciocarliei, Cluj-Napoca 400124;46.779862;23.611739;7;200;8;250;1;400
Hotel Sunny Hill;Strada Fagetului 31A, Cluj-Napoca 400497;46.716030;23.573740;4;150;6;190
Golden Tulip Ana Dome;Strada Observatorului 129, Cluj-Napoca 400352;46.751989;23.576580;0;330;0;350;0;600
```

The first line of the file is the **File Descriptor** line. The second line is a **Blank Line** simply for easier viewing of the file. The third line is considered a **Comment Line** because in this case it starts with a semi-colon (**;**). It's actually up to you to decide what is to be in place to make a file line considered as a Comment line. This line simply acts as a **Header Line** and describes what each delimited piece of data on any **Data Line** means. The fourth line is of course yet another blank line and again, for easier viewing of the file. The remaining file lines are all **Data Lines** and these are the file lines you want to process.

To read the file your methods might look like this:

```
public HotelDescriptor readLine(final String line) {
    // Split on various possible combinations of how the
    // delimiter might be formated within a file line.
    String info[] = line.split(" ; |; |;"); 
    // Variables declaration and default initialization values
    String tempname = "";
    String tempaddress = "";
    float templatitudeh = 0.0f;
    float templongitudeh = 0.0f;
    int singleroom = 0;
    int singleprice = 0;
    int doubleroom = 0;
    int doubleprice = 0;
    int suiteroom = 0;
    int suiteprice = 0;

    String strg; // Used to hold the current Array Element in the for/loop
    String regExF = "-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"; // RegEx to validate a string float or double value.
    String regExI = "\\d+";             // RegEx to validate a string Integer value.
    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        strg = info[i].trim(); // remove leading/trailing spaces if any
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                tempname = info[i];
                break;
            case 1:
                tempaddress = info[i];
                break;
            case 2:
                // Is it a float or double numerical value
                if (strg.matches(regExF)) {
                    templatitudeh = Float.parseFloat(info[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                // Is it a float or double numerical value
                if (strg.matches(regExF)) {
                    templongitudeh = Float.parseFloat(info[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                // Is it a Integer numerical value
                if (strg.matches(regExI)) {
                    singleroom = Integer.parseInt(info[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                // Is it a Integer numerical value
                if (strg.matches(regExI)) {
                    singleprice = Integer.parseInt(info[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                // Is it a Integer numerical value
                if (strg.matches(regExI)) {
                    doubleroom = Integer.parseInt(info[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                // Is it a Integer numerical value
                if (strg.matches(regExI)) {
                    doubleprice = Integer.parseInt(info[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                // Is it a Integer numerical value
                if (strg.matches(regExI)) {
                    suiteroom = Integer.parseInt(info[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                // Is it a Integer numerical value
                if (strg.matches(regExI)) {
                    suiteprice = Integer.parseInt(info[i]);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    Hotel tempHotel = new Hotel(tempname, tempaddress, templatitudeh, templongitudeh, 
            singleroom, singleprice, doubleroom, doubleprice, suiteroom, suiteprice);
    System.out.println(tempHotel.getName());
    return tempHotel;
}

public List<HotelDescriptor> readFile(final String hotels) {
    try (BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(hotels))) {
        String line;
        int lineCounter = 0;
        while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
            // Trim any leading or trailing spaces (spaces, tabs, etc)
            line = line.trim();
            lineCounter++; 
            // Is this the right file to read?
            if (lineCounter == 1) {
                if (!line.equalsIgnoreCase("My App Name - Hotels Data File")) {
                    //No it isn't...
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Hotels Data File!",
                            "Invalid Data File", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    break; // Get out of while loop
                }
                // Otherwise skip the File Descriptor line.
                else { continue; }
            }
            // Is this a blank or Comment line...
            // Lines that start with ; are comment lines
            if (line.equals("") || line.startsWith(";")) {
                // Yes it is...skip this line.
                continue;
            }
            // Process the data line...
            hotelData.add(readLine(line));
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return hotelData;
}
```

In the **readLine()** method variables are initialized to hold default values should not all values be present on any given file Data Line. The **switch** block ensures that only supplied data line values are processed regardless of how data is provided, defaults fill in the rest. This eliminates the possibility of an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** from happening when working with the **info[]** Array.

Where **parseFloat()** and **parseInt()**  are used the string to be converted into its respective data type is first checked to ensure that it is a valid numerical representation of the data type we are converting to. The [**String.matches()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method is used for this in conjunction with a regular expression.

The code above can of course be optimized much further but I feel it provides a good description of what can be done to to increase the success of reading and processing the file(s).

As a side note, it is also understandably confusing to call one of your own methods (**readLine()**) by the same name as a method used by BufferedReader. Up to you but perhaps this would be better named as **processReadLine()**

Prices should be at least in either float or double data type